# Exe destroys itself

Tags: c#, crash, exe

I have made an console app (exe) with C#. Application is used to send some http requests to server. It sends json to call server's API to execute some work. I save cookies in environmental variable.

We have noticed some weird behavior with this exe. With some sequence(we were not able to find out what sequence this is) of API calls ( api is called by command line arguments) the exe destroys itself. Its size becomes 0KB from starting 15MB. I have never seen that kind of behavior before. Do you have any idea what could it be?

This is the main part of code that creates http request, and other uploads file...

```
 static public JObject UploadFile(string fileName)
    {


        HttpWebRequest requestToServer = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverDomain + directory + "/File");


        string boundaryString = "----SomeRandomText";
        requestToServer.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        requestToServer.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        requestToServer.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString;
        requestToServer.KeepAlive = false;
        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dopinus.e2.session", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User) != null)
        {

            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            cookies.Add(new Uri(serverDomain), new Cookie("dopinus.e2.session", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dopinus.e2.session", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User).ToString()));

            requestToServer.CookieContainer = cookies;
        }

        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string boundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundaryString + "\r\n";
        byte[] boundaryStringLineBytes = ascii.GetBytes(boundaryStringLine);

        string lastBoundaryStringLine = "\r\n--" + boundaryString + "--\r\n";
        byte[] lastBoundaryStringLineBytes = ascii.GetBytes(lastBoundaryStringLine);


        string myFileDescriptionContentDisposition = String.Format(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}",
            "myFileDescription",
            "A sample file description");
        byte[] myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes = ascii.GetBytes(myFileDescriptionContentDisposition);

        string fileUrl = fileName;

        string myFileContentDisposition = String.Format(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"{0}\"; " + "filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n",
            "myFile", Path.GetFileName(fileUrl), Path.GetExtension(fileUrl));
        byte[] myFileContentDispositionBytes = ascii.GetBytes(myFileContentDisposition);

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileUrl);


        long totalRequestBodySize = boundaryStringLineBytes.Length * 2 + lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length + myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes.Length + myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length + fileInfo.Length;

        requestToServer.ContentLength = totalRequestBodySize;

        using (Stream s = requestToServer.GetRequestStream())
        {

            s.Write(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
            s.Write(myFileDescriptionContentDispositionBytes, 0,
            myFileDescriptionContentDisposition.Length);


            s.Write(boundaryStringLineBytes, 0, boundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
            s.Write(myFileContentDispositionBytes, 0,
            myFileContentDispositionBytes.Length);


            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                s.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            fileStream.Close();


            s.Write(lastBoundaryStringLineBytes, 0, lastBoundaryStringLineBytes.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = requestToServer.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string replyFromServer = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        JObject jsonResult = JObject.Parse(replyFromServer);
        //CreateErrorLog(replyFromServer);
        CreateResponse(replyFromServer);
        return jsonResult;
    }
    static public JObject request(string json)
    {



        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverDomain + directory + "/json.rpc");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dopinus.e2.session", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User) != null)
        {

            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            cookies.Add(new Uri(serverDomain), new Cookie("dopinus.e2.session", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dopinus.e2.session", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User).ToString()));

            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("dopinus.e2.session", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dopinus.e2.session", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User).ToString());
        }
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dopinus.e2.session", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User) == null)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cook in httpResponse.Cookies)
                {
                    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(cook.Name, cook.Value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
                }
            }
            else if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dopinus.e2.session", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User) != null)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cook in httpResponse.Cookies)
                {
                    if (cook.Name == "dopinus.e2.session" && cook.Value != Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("dopinus.e2.session", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User))
                    {
                        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(cook.Name, cook.Value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

                    }
                }

            }

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                JObject jsonResult = JObject.Parse(result);
                //CreateErrorLog(result);
                CreateResponse(result);
                return jsonResult;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is interesting, but it is very difficult to analyze and answer because you haven't provided [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Creating MVCE will help both you and us to understand your environment and issues better.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I just wanted to know, if anybody would know if this could be problem with sending http requests from console, or writing to environment variable, because I havent been able to reproduce problem, while it happens daily with my users. And I havent been able to find out what really causes problem, so I know its hard to answer it, but maybe somebody faced similar problem and would know something useful.. Its worth a try

Comment: As @EugenePodskal suggested, we can't tell you what's happening without some code to go off.

Comment: @NejcLovrencic I have some reservations about storing the cookies in environmental variables, but if you say that the problem is caused with some unknown sequence of user command you may try to log all user's actions(commands) before execution in some file (well, there are privacy issues, so you may want to inform them about this). Whenever the problem shows you can ask your users to give this log file for analysis. Just make sure that the logging **successfully** occurs before command execution.

Comment: @NejcLovrencic Your code still looks far too intimidating for me. But the main question - Can you reliably repeat the problem your users encounter? If not - it will be difficult for anyone to help you, so try to make this problem to appear deterministically(It does not look like race condition, so try to use logs). If yes - make your example as concise and clear as possible - remove everything nonnecessary. With some effort you will get to the gist of the problem.